# assigning a string to a complex pointer

Tags: string, pointers, struct

I'm trying to assign a string to an array defined like this

`char *(*attributes)[][2];` as defined by a library I'm using.

I want to be able to put a string into `attributes[i][0]`

I think I'm just getting confused about the pointers, I'm getting errors saying invalid use of array with unspecified bounds.

The array of attributes is stored in a struct called info.

I've tried to access it as:

`*(info->attributes)[i][0] = newAttributeName`
which makes sense to me, but as I said, isn't working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's a function pointer, or an array of function pointers.

Comment: From the description, I'm not sure thats right. It's described as an array of attributes. the first index is for the attribute number (from 1 to however many attributes are present). The second is two pieces of information about the attribute. It's name is in [0], and it's value is in [1]. Both are strings. So I'm trying to, for example, put the name of the attribute in [0][0]

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations

Comment: interesting. http://www.cdecl.org/ says 'declare attributes as pointer to array of array 2 of pointer to char'. So I was wrong. I have no idea how to use such a beast, however.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else is offering, I'd suggest:

```
char *attributesa[][2] = *attributes;
char *attributesb[2] = attributesa[0];
attributesb[0] = "Horsefeathers";
```

and then figure out how to turn that into one statement.

Comment: Thanks, thats actually a really good idea I hadn't thought of. I'll try it and post back here later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct way, for future reference:

```
(*info->attributes)[i][0] = someString;
```

The trick is the parenthesis give precedence to info->attributes being dereferenced, because otherwise it will try to find [i][0] first.